# Where is the UV vertex pane located?

Tags: uv, vertex-groups

I would like to follow a tutorial video. In this tutorial, the author uses the UV vertex pane:

[image]

However, I don't find it. 
How could I bring this pane up?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just press `N` key

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos When I do that, a pane does pop up, but I don't see the "UVs" section in it. I do see the "Display" section, but unlike the screenshot, above that I see ""Item", and above that "3D Cursor". I'm in edit mode, and on the left side I have selected "UV/Image Editor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UV window on the left side, it's necessary to press N again.
Unless I do, the window on the left side doesn't have any pane.
What I thought was "the" pane was a pane of the 3D view window on the right side.